# Jupyter Server Extension config option not recognized

Tags: jupyter, config

I have built a jupyter server extension (which introduces additional endpoints to what normal jupyter server has to offer). When I try to start the server and the extension, the startup works, and the server is running:

```
[I 2023-09-26 23:35:57.861 ServerApp] Package canvas_ext took 0.0242s to import
[W 2023-09-26 23:35:57.863 CanvasApplication] Config option `disable_check_xsrf` not recognized by `CanvasApplication`.
[W 2023-09-26 23:35:57.863 CanvasApplication] Config option `allow_origin` not recognized by `CanvasApplication`.
[I 2023-09-26 23:35:57.863 ServerApp] canvas_ext | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-09-26 23:35:57.878 CanvasApplication] Config {'ServerApp': {'config_file': '../server_config.py', 'root_dir': '/Users/digib', 'jpserver_extensions': {'canvas_ext': True}, 'disable_check_xsrf': True, 'allow_origin': '*'}, 'CanvasApplication': {'disable_check_xsrf': True, 'allow_origin': '*'}}
[I 2023-09-26 23:35:57.878 ServerApp] canvas_ext | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-09-26 23:35:57.880 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/digib
[I 2023-09-26 23:35:57.880 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 2.5.0 is running at:
[I 2023-09-26 23:35:57.880 ServerApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=1ffa63a811c34827db49b3f6273c418ac51e98418abb90b1
[I 2023-09-26 23:35:57.880 ServerApp]     http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=1ffa63a811c34827db49b3f6273c418ac51e98418abb90b1
[I 2023-09-26 23:35:57.880 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 2023-09-26 23:35:57.882 ServerApp]
```

The extension (canvas_ext) loaded successfully, and I can call my additional endpoints.

Now I need to add some configurations to the server, namely I want to add the `allow_origin` and the `disable_check_xsrf` fields. I have created a config file `server_config.py` which is also successfully loaded. However, the fields are not set for the extension.

This is my config file (called server_config.py):

```
import os

c.ServerApp.root_dir = os.path.expanduser("~")  # type:ignore[name-defined]
c.ServerApp.jpserver_extensions = { "canvas_ext": True }  # type:ignore[name-defined]
c.ServerApp.disable_check_xsrf = True  # type:ignore[name-defined]
c.ServerApp.allow_origin = "*"  # type:ignore[name-defined]

c.CanvasApplication.disable_check_xsrf = True  # type:ignore[name-defined]
c.CanvasApplication.allow_origin = "*"  # type:ignore[name-defined]
```

I run the server with this command:
`jupyter server --config=../server_config.py`

The fields are correctly set for the base Server (ServerApp), but cannot be loaded for the CanvasApplication (my extension). I have also tried to start the server with the flags `--CanvasApplication.allow_origin="*"`, which also resulted in the same warning:

```
[W 2023-09-26 23:35:57.863 CanvasApplication] Config option `allow_origin` not recognized by `CanvasApplication`.
```

Additionally, what seems to be a bit suspicious, is the fact that the command `jupyter canvas_ext` does not start my extension (which one would expect).

when I run `jupyter server extension list`, it lists canvas_ext, so it should be ready to go, no?

Am I missing something here?